# Is there a way to capture text messages into an image?

Tags: iphone

On the iPhone, if you hold down the Power button + Main button, it'll take an image of what's on the screen.  I've used it in the past to capture and print out text message exchanges.

Is there a way to do this if the text message exchanges span multiple pages?

Comment: Do you happen to have/use software that lets you back up your SMSes?

Comment: So which one you actually mean? "How can I capture the whole screen down the scrollbar to the bottom to an image" or "How can I save my SMS text messages"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [PhoneView](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/). It can convert your SMS logs to PDF files for viewing or printing.

Answer (score 2):

Only by scrolling and capturing repeatedly and then assembling in a graphics program. Nothing built into iOS currently does it, and SMS data is completely inaccessible to App Store 3rd party apps (protecting your privacy).